# Determine if a sequence converges before finding the limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I've got an exam in a couple of days and one of the exercises in my book is:

> Determine the convergence of this sequence, then, if the sequence converges, find the limit.
> $$\sqrt{n-1} - \sqrt n$$

Now I know how I'd find the limit, that's not a problem. But how do I find out if the sequence converges before finding the limit, as the exercise implies I should do?

Edit: what I would probably do is find the limit, then say that the existance of a limit `L` in `R` implies that it's convergent

Comment: Try multiplying above and below by $\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Hint: What is $(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})$?

Comment: Yep, I would get 1 over something with n. Would that be a rigorous enough proof of convergence though? Thank you.

Comment: I think you may be overhinking this: if you know how to find the limit, then your reasoning must show that the sequence converges. Perhaps you should show us your working for finding the limit.

Comment: I figured that that's the case. You guys helped me in just the way I needed. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can show that your sequence is increasing and bounded above. Do you see how you can do this to $\sqrt{n-1}-\sqrt{n}$ ?

Comment: That's what was on my mind. But is there an example where the sequence is convergent, but it's not bounded or not monotonic? Does your method work for all sequences? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, I don't think that would be a problem

Comment: $$\left\{\frac{(-1)^n}n\right\}\;$$ is not monotonic yet it converges to zero. And any convergent sequence is bounded.

Comment: I understand. Thanks for pointing that out